# Apache AIRFLOW - How to send arguments to Python Script

Tags: python, airflow

In `Admin->Connection` I set an `Conn Type S3`.

Basically I have this code in My Python script:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "..."
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "..."
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION = "..."
    Start_Work
```

What I want to do is call my script from Airflow and pass to it the arguments for the connection (instead of hard code them in the script).

How do I do that?

Let's assume that this is the connection:
[image]

How do I access each filed data?

Answer (score 8):

One thing you can do is import the `provide_session` util to then retrieve the connection based on the `conn_id`. You can then pass that to the python operator.

So it would look something like this:

```
from airflow.utils.db import provide_session

@provide_session
def get_conn(conn_id, session=None):
    conn = (session.query(Connection)
                   .filter(Connection.conn_id == conn_id)
                   .first())
    return conn

def my_python_function():

   conn = get_conn('connection_id')

   key_id = conn.extra_dejson.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
   secret_key = conn.extra_dejson.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
   default_region = conn.extra_dejson.get('DEFAULT_REGION')

task1 = PythonOperator(task_id='my_task', python_callable=my_python_function, dag=dag)

task1
```

EDIT: Removed quotes from python callable

Comment: It shows: Can't decrypt `extra` params for login=None, FERNET_KEY configuration is missing

Comment: @jack Yeah, you probably want to work with higher level access from Airflow code.

Comment: @dlamblin Some of my scripts connect to S3. I don't want to hard code the connection details in each one of them. I want to set it in one place.

Comment: this implementation didn't work in airflow 2.0

Answer (score 1):

I see your connection ID is `M_1` and your connection type is `S3` so you can load this inside a `PythonOperator` (or a python script called from `BashOperator`) with:

```
from airflow.hooks.s3_hook import S3Hook

def py_op_callable:
    hook = S3Hook('M_1')
    botocore_credentials = hook.get_credentials()
    botocore_credentials.access_key
    botocore_credentials.secret_key
    botocore_credentials.token
```

On v1.9.0 it seems `get_credentials` is not yet there. There's only the private `_get_credentials()` on AwsHook which S3Hook inherits. If you're sure you put them into the extra parameters the direct approach is:

```
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook

def py_op_callable:
    hook = BaseHook('M_1')
    extra = hook.get_connection().extra_dejson
    key_id = extra.get('aws_access_key_id')
    secret_key = extra.get('aws_secret_access_key')
    default_region = extra.get('region_name')
    return key_id,secret_key,default_region
```

Comment: 'S3Hook' object has no attribute 'get_credentials'

Comment: @jack It does in v1.10.0 test. In v1.9.0 there is a private _get_credentials on AwsHook which S3Hook inherits.